# charmed kubeflow control panel access

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, juju

This is probably a classical case of - error 40 - [*]. I setup the canonical charmed kubeflow according to the [official guide](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/get-started-with-charmed-kubeflow). I use kvm virtual machine to make it easy deployment/cleanup.

I have links installed in my vm and can see the website for control panel loads, but complains about lack of javascript(expeted), but when I try to use the same address from the host machine, it fails to resolve. I tried to setup a proxy, but kubectl refuses to work - there's no config in the ~/.kube (not even an empty one)

- How do I get the control panel exposed to the host machine (and in the future to the entire network)?
- Can I use kubectl with cluster deployed by juju? Are there any special requirements for that?

I never used *juju* before, but I assumed everything would be deployed and configured automagically.
Since I followed the steps from the aforementioned official guide. I'll greatly appreciate help - and even more some explanation!

**Kubectl error Sample:**

```
test02@k8-vm:~$ kubectl get pods
E0111 10:43:26.229932 1465943 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0111 10:43:26.231503 1465943 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0111 10:43:26.232066 1465943 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0111 10:43:26.234371 1465943 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0111 10:43:26.235000 1465943 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

**juju status:**

```
Model     Controller  Cloud/Region      Version  SLA          Timestamp
kubeflow  uk8sx       my-k8s/localhost  3.1.7    unsupported  11:09:48Z
admission-webhook/0*          active    idle       10.1.84.76
... //all services green
training-operator/0*          active    idle       10.1.84.115
```

[*] - error 40 is sitting 40cm from the screen ;)